# How to use ForkJoinPool in Spring Boot @Async?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java.util.concurrent, forkjoinpool

I want to use ForkJoinPool in my spring boot project with @Async annotation like ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

**For Example :-**

```
 @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        return executor;
    }
```

i use https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-creating-asynchronous-methods-using-as this link in my code but i want to use ForkJoinPool like this.

Comment: Why do you want to use ForkJoinPool?

Answer (score 5):

It's fine to use ForkJoinPool with asynch. This approach is not exactly what ForkJoinPool was design for - which is solving Divide and Conquer task and using work stealing algorithm, but to execute event-style or IO blocking tasks, and it's a valid use case.

So with basic usage, you can do:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomething(), ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
```

You can also create custom ForkJoinPool in Asynch mode. Workers in a ForkJoinPool in async mode process tasks in FIFO (first in, first out) order. By default, ForkJoinPools process such tasks in LIFO (last in, first out) order. Also the async mode setting only concerns forked tasks that are never joined. Can be used for event-style tasks that are submitted but never joined (tasks that are executed for their side-effects, not for returning a result that will be processed by the forking task and then joining).

You can create custom ForkJoinPool with given parallelism in asynch mode like this (the first param is pool size, last - bool asyncMode):

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(
             6, ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, true);
```

So what you are after is:

```
    @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(
             6, ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, true);
        return pool;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, you can't combine `@Async` annotation with `ForkJoinPool` class. `ForkJoinPool` is dedicated to split one task into subtask to execute it in a parallel way and merge it into a result. A parallel stream is [using](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool) `ForkJoinPool` behind the scenes. To execute the task using `ForkJoinPool` you need to implement `RecursiveTask` or `RecursiveAction` interface. I didn't meet any way how we can use those things together.

Comment: thanks for reply, ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and ForkJoinPool both are use of ExecutorService interface.

Comment: Yes, both implement `ExecutorService` interface, but executor for `@Async` annotation need to by implementation of `TaskExecutor` interface which is implemented by `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, but not by `ForkJoinPool`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you wanna do this, but still you can use `ForkJoinPool` for `@Async`, Since `ForkJoinPool` is implementing class of `Executor`

But if we look at the [ForkJoinPool-documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), i don't see any method to set the thread pool size and it's your risk to use it.

**config**

```
@Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    return pool;
}
```

**Service**

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public void testRun()  {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

**Output**

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
```

And if you are much interested to use `ForkJoinPool` use `CompletableFuture.async` methods instead of spring boot `@Async` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

> All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task)

Answer (score 1):

To enable Spring’s asynchronous method execution capability you can use the `@EnableAsync` annotation in configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ThreadConfig {
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("prate");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

In some cases, you don’t want the same thread pool to run all of the application’s tasks. you might want separate threads pools with different configurations backing our functions.
So you can configure specific `ThreadPoolExecutor` like -

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ThreadConfig {
    @Bean(name = "specificTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor specificTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Now the function should set the qualifier value to determine the target executor of a specific Executor or TaskExecutor.

```
@Async("specificTaskExecutor")
public void runFromAnotherThreadPool() {
    System.out.println("test here");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ,but i want to use forkjoinpool like "yourspecificTaskExecutor" your bean, so can you help me in creating my method asynchronously using ForkJoinPool in Spring boot